# Запятая перед сравнительным оборотом

Tags: пунктуация, как, сравнительный-оборот

В этих предложениях запятая перед *как*?

> "Лес был как море и море как лес". "Весной жизнь как река".

Answer (score 1):

(1) **Лес был как море и море как лес**, Небо нависло над ними. Ты ― существо из разряда чудес, Мой позабытый любимый.

Запятая не ставится при наличии союза КАК. http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=106#pp106

По поводу запятой перед союзом И.

Это ССП, обычно перед союзом И  запятая ставится. Но содержание непонятно, может быть, есть общий элемент, отменяющий запятую (например: так как небо нависло над ними).

(2) Весной **жизнь как река** ― одни переходят через реку, другие остаются.

Весной ― общее обстоятельство, запятая не ставится при наличии союза КАК.

В качестве варианта: Весной **жизнь как река:**  одни переходят через реку, другие остаются.

Второе предложение поясняет первое, поэтому двоеточие является классическим знаком, но может заменяться тире.

Примечание: в обоих случаях для решения задачи **необходим контекст.**

Comment: Улица была как буря. Будет ли перед " как" запятая?

Comment: Нет запятой.  Сравнительный оборот "как буря"  является именной частью составного сказуемого, "была" - связка, а в настоящем времени связка пропущена: улица как буря.  .В предложении "Улица была // как буря"  делается небольшая пауза на месте перелома интонации, как и во всяком простом предложении, но запятой она не обозначается. В авторском варианте возможно тире,  а не запятая, оно обозначает увеличенную паузу: Улица - как буря. Улица была - как буря. Сравнить: Улица, как буря, ревела, грохотала. Здесь сравнительный оборот, обособленный  запятыми.